# Where is the ToList() method? (IQueryable)

Tags: c#, .net, linq, extension-methods

If I try this, it will work:

```
var query = myContextObject.Users.Where(u=>u.Name == "John");
query.ToList();
```

I'm able to call `ToList` and a lot of other extension methods.

But if I try this:

```
public List ConvertQueryToList(IQueryable query)
{
    return query.ToList();
}
```

`ToList` won't be accessible, I'm guessing this is because `ToList` is an extension method, but then how is that `ToList` is attached in the first example?
Is it possible to access `ToList` in the second case?

Comment: Note: `var query` != `iQueryable query`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to write it as:

```
public List<T> ConvertQueryToList<T>(IQueryable<T> query)
{
    return query.ToList();
}
```

This will cause the `IQueryable<T>` to return the appropriate `List<T>`, since the [`Enumerable.ToList()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) method requires an `IEnumerable<T>` as input (which also works with `IQueryable<T>`, as [`IQueryable<T>` inherits `IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351562.aspx)).

That being said, there is really no reason to use it this way.  You can always just call `ToList()` directly if you need to create a `List<T>` - abstracting inside of a second layer just confuses the API further.

If you're trying to convert a non-generic [IQueryable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.iqueryable.aspx) interface, you would need to do something like:

```
public List<T> ConvertQueryToList<T>(IQueryable query)
{
    return query.Cast<T>.ToList();
}
```

This would then require calling like:

```
var results = ConvertQueryToList<SomeType>(queryable);
```

Alternatively, if you want to leave this non-generic (which I wouldn't recommend), then you could use:

```
public ArrayList ConvertQueryToList(IQueryable query)
{
    ArrayList results = new ArrayList();
    results.AddRange(query.Cast<object>().ToList());
    return results;
}
```

Comment: I'm not trying to abstract "ToList" my purpose was just to make my problem easier to explain. Thanks for all the info!

Comment: @marcos.borunda Wasn't sure exactly what your goal was, based on the question.  I tried to cover the three main options here, though - it make sense now?

Comment: Somewhere between the cast approach and the arraylist approach is `query.Cast<object>.ToList()`. It basically is the cast approach, but because everything can be cast to `object`, it works with any `IQueryable`.

Comment: @JonHanna Yeah - you'll get a `List<object>` as a result, then.  I thought about including that, but it seemed like an odd approach, too

Comment: The last example doesn't actually work. `ArrayList.AddRange` expects an `ICollection` with `IQueryable` isn't.

Comment: I dont see why you wrap the List<object> into an ArrayList in the end.

Comment: Agree with the last comments. It seems better to simply `foreach` with the `ArrayList` instead of making an extra intermediate collection. So `var results = new ArrayList(); foreach (var obj in query) { results.Add(obj; } return results;` Another comment: The asker may want to make such a method `static`.

Answer (score 10):

The first of your examples returns an `IQueryable<T>`, whereas in the second you're using `IQueryable` (without the Generic Type parameter).

You can check out the two completely different interfaces [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351562.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.iqueryable.aspx).

Comment: One place I've seen `IQueryable` (non generic) is the dynamic linq provider for Linq-To-SQL. As the dynamic linq provider takes strings as arguments it doesn't have a type to work with.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an extension method for this:

```
public static class ListHelper
{
    public static IList ToList(this IQueryable query)
    {
        var genericToList = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("ToList")
            .MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { query.ElementType });
        return (IList)genericToList.Invoke(null, new[] { query });
    }
}
```

Comment: This led me to the right direction. You can achieve the same result with "query.Cast<object>().ToList()".

Answer (score -1):

Here is a generic extension method for the case you are using `IQueryable<<T>>`.

Of course it is not absolutely safe because the type could be wrong and the cast could fail. So please be careful if you use that method.

```csharp
using System.Collections.Generic;
  
namespace System.Linq
{
    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static List<T> ToList<T>(this IQueryable queryable)
        {
            return ((IQueryable<T>)queryable).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should describe why the author can't use `ToList` in his second code snipped. Your answer might be working but is not hinting to the problem's source.