# Returning an IQueryable of any kind

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to define a delegate type to return my data set.

```
public Func<ArticleServerEntities, object, IQueryable<object>> GetItemsSource { get; set; }
```

Here's how I populate it.

```
class TextValuePair
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
}

GetItemsSource = (ctx, val) => ctx.Set<Category>()
                                  .OrderBy(c => c.Title)
                                  .Select(c => new TextValuePair { Text = c.Title, Value = c.Id }),
```

And here's how I call it.

```
using (var context = new ArticleServerEntities())
{
    action.ListBox.ItemsSource = action.GetItemsSource(context, parentValue).ToList();
}
```

But calling it generates a `System.NotSupportedException` exception.

> Unable to cast the type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.

Although the error message doesn't quite make sense to me, I believe this is related to the fact that the delegate returns `IQueryable<TextValuePair>` instead of `IQueryable<object>`.

But in practice I need this delegate to be able to return an `IQueryable` of any kind--just as `ListBox.ItemsSource` accepts a collection of any type.

Does anyone see a way around this, or better understand the error message?

Comment: Why not returning just an `IQueryable` instead of `IQueryable<T>`?

Comment: @dotctor: `IQueryable` does not have a `ToList()` method.

Comment: Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37853007/3970411)

Comment: @dotctor: Can anyone explain to me why this would be necessary? We have `ToList()` methods of all types. Why not for `IQueryable`?

Comment: `ToList` returns `List<T>`, `IQueryable` is not generic.

Comment: @dotctor: Thanks, but it looks like the last line of your extension method throws the same exception for me.

Comment: What is the `val` in `(ctx, val)`? Have you used it anywhere? Are you posting the complete code?

Comment: @dotctor: `ctx` is my `DbContext`. In this case, `val` is just `null`. (As you can see, my delegate doesn't use it.) There is more code, but the statements I've posted are unchanged from my real code.

Comment: Are you still using the `IQueryable<object>`? Have you tried changing it to `IQueryable`?

Comment: @dotctor: Yes, I changed my delegate type to `Func<ArticleServerEntities, object, IQueryable>` and then plugged in your `ToList()` extension method. That's all I changed.

Comment: Can you post the code for `Category`?

Comment: @dotctor: `Category` is a database entity. I'm not really sure what code you want to see. `Title` is a string, and `Id` is an int.

Comment: @dotctor: Ivan nailed it. My bad. Thanks for the extension method though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message indicates that the problem is in this projection:

```
.Select(c => new TextValuePair { Text = c.Title, Value = c.Id }),
```

Most likely your `TextValuePair` `Value` member is of type `object`, while your `Id` is of type `int`.

In order to avoid the unsupported cast, you should really project to some generic class like

```
class TextValuePair<TValue>
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public TValue Value { get; set; }
}
```

and then

```
.Select(c => new TextValuePair<int> { Text = c.Title, Value = c.Id }),
```

Comment: OMG, you are exactly right. It was `int`, but I had apparently set it to `object` while trying different things and then forgot. I've very impressed that you were able to see through that.

Comment: Thank you, but it wasn't a big deal. When you see *Unable to cast the type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Object'* the first thing you ask yourself is where the heck I assign  `int` to `object` :)

Comment: Yes, I asked myself that but incorrectly made the assumption that Id was _still_ an int.